# c++ How to read a wchar_t* to into a std::wsting variable and print in HEX

Tags: c++, hex, wchar-t, wstring

In main I have a wstring mystr that contains unicode characters.

```
int main()
{
   std::wcout << std::hex << 16 << endl;
   std::wstring mystr = L"abc - ";
   result = myfun(mystr);

   // here I want to print out my variable result 
   //std::wcout << hex<<result;
}
```

I also have a function *myfun* which takes this wstring and prints out every letter (in HEX!) surrounded by brackets using a *incrementfun* -function. This works OK.

```
std::wstring myfun(std::wstring mystr){  
    wchar_t* ptrToCC = &mystr[0]    ;
    std::wstring Out    ;

    while (*ptrToCC != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "(" << std::hex << *ptrToCC << ")";       // first print is OK
        ptrToCC = incrementfun(ptrToCC);   
    }
    Out = "(" + std::hex + *ptrToCC + ")"                      // none of this not works
    Out = "(" + *ptrToCC + ")";
    Out  << "(" << std::hex << *ptrToCC << ")";

    return Out;
}
```

In the first print this function prints out the following line which is fine

```
(61)(62)(63)(20)(2d)(20)
```

Now I want to use the function myfun to return values to main, I tried to read the values into a variable to pass it back. But I am not able to read them into a variable and therefore I cannot print it in main. **How can I read the values and print them out in main as HEX ?**

Comment: Use wstringstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`std::wstringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

**Edit:** Edited to use [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```cpp
std::wstring myfun(std::wstring const& mystr) {  
    std::wstringstream out;

    for (auto const& ch : mystr)
        out << "(" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(ch) << ")";

    return out.str();
}
```

Comment: No need for the pointer.  `auto myfun(std::wstring mystr) -> std::wstring { std::wostringstream out; auto const w = sizeof(wchar_t) * 2; for (auto c : mystr) { out << L"(" << std::hex << std::setw(w) << std::setfill(L'0') << std::uppercase << +c << L")"; } return out.str(); }`

Comment: You should use [`std::wostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead, since you don't use the input capabilities of `std::wstringstream`.